# C++ Variadic class template design

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates

I'm working on a mix-in type Config Reader class which supports reading configuration data from environment, command line, files, etc..

I was kind of following the std::tuple type design:

```
template <class... Ts> struct ConfigReader {};

template <class T, class... Ts>
class ConfigReader<T, Ts...> : ConfigReader<Ts...>
{
  public:
    typedef boost::fusion::set<T, Ts...> sequence_type;

    ConfigReader(T t, Ts... ts)
      : ConfigReader<Ts...>(ts...)
      , parameters_(t, ts...)
    {
      this->init();
    }

  private:
    sequence_type parameters_;

    void init()
    {
       boost::fusion::for_each(parameters_, SetFromEnvironment());
       boost::fusion::for_each(parameters_, SetFromCommandLine());
       boost::fusion::for_each(parameters_, SetFromConfigFile());
    }
};
```

But I realized that I could also define this without the recursive inheritance

```
template <class T, class... Ts>
class ConfigReader<T, Ts...>
{
  public:
    typedef boost::fusion::set<T, Ts...> sequence_type;

    ConfigReader(T t, Ts... ts)
      : parameters_(t, ts...)
    {
      this->init();
    }

    template <class Type>
    typename boost::fusion::result_of::value_at_key<Sequence const, Type>::type get()
    {
      return boost::fusion::at_key<Type>(parameters);
    }

  private:
    sequence_type parameters_;

    void init()
    {
       boost::fusion::for_each(parameters_, SetFromEnvironment());
       boost::fusion::for_each(parameters_, SetFromCommandLine());
       boost::fusion::for_each(parameters_, SetFromConfigFile());
    }
};
```

The latter case seems to work better because init() is only called once which is really what I want. But now I'm confused as to what are the differences between the two? Am I losing something without the recursive inheritance?

Simplified usage would be.. (Ignoring Parameter type structs)

```
int main()
{
  ConfigReader<Start, End, Resources> configReader(Start(), End("infinity"), Resources());

  Start startTime = configReader.get<Start>();
}
```

Comment: It's unclear what it is you're doing. In particular, is there a reason you're not just using `std::tuple`? What is `init()` and where is it defined?

Comment: I added some more info.. But does that really influence the answer to what's the difference between the recursive inheritance and not?

Answer (score 0):

The recursive approach makes no sense. Consider an example case where you want:

```
ConfigReader<A, B, C> reader(A{}, B{}, C{});
```

In the recursive case, you end up with this hierarchy:

```
ConfigReader<A, B, C> has three readers: A, B, C
    |
    |
    V
ConfigReader<B, C> has two readers: B, C
    |
    |
    V
ConfigReader<C> has one reader: C
```

You have 6 readers, when you meant for only 3! What you *probably* meant when you did the recursive hierarchy is for each instantiation to just have *one* reader: not all of them. That is:

```
template <typename T, typename... Ts>
struct ConfigReader : ConfigReader<Ts...> {
    T current;

    ConfigReader(T t, Ts... ts)
    : ConfigReader<Ts...>(ts...)
    , current(t)
    { }
};
```

But what you're doing with the boost fusion set accomplishes that directly. Though, with C++11, you should probably just stick with:

```
template <typename... T>
struct ConfigReader {
    std::tuple<T...> readers;
};
```

It should suit your purpose.

Comment: Yes I started with using a tuple, but I think the supporting fusion infrastructure has a lot of utilities that I need, such as my get() function which specifies the parameter type instead of the index used in a tuple.

Comment: @mike C++14 adds [`std::get<T>()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/get) as well. You could additionally implement that fairly easily, and avoid all the cruft that mpl.fusion brings in.

Comment: Ah interesting on the C++14 addition I didn't know that. I agree mpl/fusion has a lot of baggage. I could probably implement those utilities (or at least hobble though, given my templating experience)